# VSCode Intellisense Not Working In Jupyter Notebook Extension(MacOS)

Tags: visual-studio-code, parameters, jupyter-notebook, arguments, intellisense

I have an issue with VS Code which I recently installed in my MacOS BigSur.
I tried out the Jupyter Notebook extension and in their documentation it says that they have full intellisense support for this extension as well.

Intellisense in Jupyter Notebook in VSCode works well for completing variables, functions,methods,etc....

The only issue I have is that I am not able to get the arguments/parameter information, though it is working fine with the python extension of VSCode

I tried out things like Shift+TAB...which works in JupyterNotebooks(not the VS Code version).

Is this a bug that I am facing...or is it just like that. Can you also please suggest as to how to make this work.

Comment: I tried multiple other things, but am not able to figure it out. If anyone knows about this issue, please do help!

Answer (score 4):

Edit May 12, 2021: With the Pylance language server (now the default), I now get parameters and type hints.

According to this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1375), the arg/param info is not supported on stable VS Code. It looks like you need to use the "Native Notebook" in VS Code Insiders (the beta) and use the "Pylance" language server Extension.

I haven't tried this solution myself (not sure I want to install Insiders), but just changing the language server to "Pylance" at least gives you signatures.

Comment: Oh okay, not sure about installing the insiders version as well, do you know when "Native Notebook" would be available in main VS Code